# Actionscript 3.0 - tracing the path of a moving body ;

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm learning AS3.0 currently. I am trying to design a simple two body planet simulation. I need to show the paths of the planets on the screen. So my question is, once I have the updated x and y coordinates for the planets at each Timer interval, how do I change the color of the pixel (x,y) of the stage so that it shows the path of the planets? Is there some command of the form stage.x = color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using [BitmapData's draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) method to render your planets as pixels each time you update them. It basically works like a 'screenshot' of the display object you pass it as n argument. If you pass the objects transformation, the position/rotation/scale will be visible (as opposed to drawing from 0,0). This way, you will only be updating pixels instead of continuously creating new display objects.

Here's a basic commented example:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

var trails:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,true,0x00000000);//create a transparent bitmap to draw the trails into
var trailsFade:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,0.025,0,0,0,1);//color transform: keep rgb the same(1,1,1), set alpha to 0.025 out of 1.0
var background:Bitmap = addChild(new Bitmap(trails,PixelSnapping.AUTO,true)) as Bitmap;//add the trails pixels/bitmap data into a Bitmap/display object at the bottom of the display list

var dot:Sprite = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
dot.graphics.lineStyle(3);
dot.graphics.drawCircle(-4, -4, 8);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event):void{
    dot.x = mouseX;
    dot.y = mouseY;
    //draw trails of the dot
    trails.draw(dot,dot.transform.concatenatedMatrix,trailsFade);//draw the dot into the bitmap data using the dot's transformation (x,y, rotation, scale)
}
```

Notice the trails when you move the mouse and how they are affected by the (update) speed.

Here's a longer example using multiple objects:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

var w:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var h:Number = stage.stageHeight;
var trails:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w,h,true,0x00000000);//create a transparent bitmap to draw the trails into
var trailsFade:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,0.025,0,0,0,0.1);//color transform: keep rgb the same(1,1,1), set alpha to 0.025 out of 1.0
var background:Bitmap = addChild(new Bitmap(trails,PixelSnapping.AUTO,true)) as Bitmap;//add the trails pixels/bitmap data into a Bitmap/display object at the bottom of the display list
var spheres:Sprite    = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;//add a container for all the spheres (planets/moons/sun/etc.)

var mercuryPivot:Sprite = spheres.addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
var venusPivot:Sprite   = spheres.addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
var earthPivot:Sprite   = spheres.addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;

var sun:Sprite     = spheres.addChild(getCircleSprite(69.5500 /4,0xFF9900)) as Sprite;
var mercury:Sprite = mercuryPivot.addChild(getCircleSprite(24.40 / 4,0xCECECE)) as Sprite;
var venus:Sprite   = venusPivot.addChild(getCircleSprite(60.52 / 4,0xFF2200)) as Sprite;
var earth:Sprite   = earthPivot.addChild(getCircleSprite(60.52 / 4,0x2233FE)) as Sprite;

mercury.x = 5791 / 40;
venus.x   = 10820 / 40;
earth.x   = 14960 / 40;
spheres.x = (w-spheres.width) * 0.5;
spheres.y = (h-spheres.height) * 0.5;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event):void{
    mercuryPivot.rotation += 0.5;
    venusPivot.rotation   += 0.25;
    earthPivot.rotation   += 0.12;
    //draw trails
    trails.draw(spheres,spheres.transform.concatenatedMatrix,trailsFade);
}


function getCircleSprite(radius:Number,color:int):Sprite{
    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(color);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(-radius * .5,-radius * .5,radius);//draw from centre
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    return circle;
}
```

Notice we call `trails.draw(spheres,spheres.transform.concatenatedMatrix,trailsFade);`
but it could be `trails.draw(earth,earth.transform.concatenatedMatrix,trailsFade);` if you only want to draw the trails of `earth`.

[image: trails]

In the example above I'm just nesting sprites and using the rotation property to keep things simple. You might want to use a bit of trigonometry to update positions because planets will probably not have perfectly circular orbits and pass through the exact location every single time.

**Update**

Thinking about this more, using the old school [Graphics API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) might be handy for you if you get started and haven't got used to playing with pixels yet.

It's easy to get started with: objects that can be displayed in flash player can have a graphics property (see the Shape/Sprite/MovieClip classes). (You can have display object that you can't draw into whether you can nest elements into (DisplayObjectContainer) or not(DisplayObject), but that's a whole other thing for you too look into).

This `graphics` property Sprites and MovieClip has allows you to draw programmatically using simply commands such as: setting a stroke(`lineStyle()`), a fill (`beginFill()`/`endFill()`), moving an imaginary 'pen' without drawing (`moveTo`), drawing a line (`lineTo`), a circle, a rectangle, a rounded rectangle, etc. It's all there.

So, a minimal drawing program would look a bit like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var mousePressed:Boolean = false;//keep track if the mouse is pressed or not
graphics.lineStyle(1);//set the stroke to have a thickness of 1 (and the other parameters are defaults(color: black, transparency: 100% / 1.0, etc.))

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseEventHandler);//listend for mouse down
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseEventHandler);//...and mouse up changes
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);//update continuously

function mouseEventHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
    mousePressed = (e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN);
    graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);//place the graphics 'pen' at this new location
}
function update(e:Event):void{
    if(mousePressed)  graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);//if the mouse is pressed, keep drawing a line to the current mouse location   
}
```

or a more complex version where you use the speed of the mouse movement to influence the stroke thickness and transparency:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;

var prevPos:Point = new Point();//previous mouse position
var currPos:Point = new Point();//current mouse position
var w:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var h:Number = stage.stageHeight;
var mousePressed:Boolean = false;//keep track if the mouse is pressed or not
graphics.lineStyle(1);//set the stroke to have a thickness of 1 (and the other parameters are defaults(color: black, transparency: 100% / 1.0, etc.))
stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseEventHandler);//listend for mouse down
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseEventHandler);//...and mouse up changes
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent):void{graphics.clear()});//double click to clear
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);//update continuously

function mouseEventHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
    mousePressed = (e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN);
    graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
}
function update(e:Event):void{
    //currPos.setTo(mouseX,mouseY);//this works for flash player 11 and above instead of setting x,y separately
    currPos.x = mouseX;
    currPos.y = mouseY;
    var mappedValue: Number = Point.distance(currPos,prevPos) / (w+h);//map the distance between points
    //prevPos.copyFrom(currPos);//this works for flash player 11 and above instead of setting x,y separately
    prevPos.x = mouseX;
    prevPos.y = mouseY;
    graphics.lineStyle(mappedValue * 100,0,1.0-(0.25+mappedValue));
    if(mousePressed)  graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);//if the mouse is pressed, keep drawing a line to the current mouse location   
}
```

So going back to the tracing of a planet path, using the graphics api, my previous example would look like so:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.geom.Point;

var w:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var h:Number = stage.stageHeight;
var hasMoved:Boolean  = false;//has the graphics 'pen' been moved ?
var spheres:Sprite    = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;//add a container for all the spheres (planets/moons/sun/etc.)

var earthPivot:Sprite = spheres.addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;

var sun:Sprite     = spheres.addChild(getCircleSprite(69.5500 /4,0xFF9900)) as Sprite;
var earth:Sprite   = earthPivot.addChild(getCircleSprite(60.52 / 4,0x2233FE)) as Sprite;

earth.x   = 14960 / 40;
spheres.x = (w-spheres.width) * 0.5;
spheres.y = (h-spheres.height) * 0.5;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event):void{
    earthPivot.rotation   += 0.12;
    //draw trails
    drawTrail(earth,0x0000FF);
}

function drawTrail(s:Sprite,color:int) {
    var globalPos:Point = s.localToGlobal(new Point());//convert the local position of the sprite (it might have been nested several times) to the global/stage coordinate system
    if(!hasMoved){//if the graphics 'pen' wasn't moved (is still at 0,0), this will happen only once: the 1st time you draw the mouse position
        graphics.moveTo(globalPos.x,globalPos.y);//move it to where we're about to draw first
        hasMoved = true;//and make sure we've marked that the above was done
    }
    graphics.lineStyle(1,color);
    graphics.lineTo(globalPos.x,globalPos.y);
}

function getCircleSprite(radius:Number,color:int):Sprite{
    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(color);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(-radius * .5,-radius * .5,radius);//draw from centre
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    return circle;
}
```

[image: trails with graphics api]

From my experience, using this older drawing API can get slow if you have a lot of lines on stage. I say older because it might actually be 15 years old now. Flash Player 10 introduced a newer drawing API. You can read on it on the [Adobe Devnet](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/drawing_commands_as3.html) but I warmly recommend [Senocular's Flash Player 10 Drawing API Tutorial](http://senocular.com/flash/tutorials/flash10drawingapi/) and his [slides and example code from Flash Camp](http://web.archive.org/web/20081216021342/http://typeof.info/flashcampdapi/)

Back to pixels: it's not that hard. You use the BitmapData class to manipulate pixels and use a Bitmap instance so you can add those pixels on stage. Here's a minimal drawing program:

```
var canvas:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,false,0xFFFFFF);//setup pixels
addChild(new Bitmap(canvas));//add them to the stage
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);//setup continuous updates
function update(e:Event):void{
    canvas.setPixel(int(mouseX),int(mouseY),0x990000);//pretty easy, right ?
}
```

want to make trippy patterns, sure thing, have a play:

```
var canvas:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,false,0xFFFFFF);//setup pixels
addChild(new Bitmap(canvas));//add them to the stage
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);//setup continuous updates
function update(e:Event):void{
    canvas.lock();//when updating multiple pixels or making multiple pixel operations
    canvas.perlinNoise(mouseX,mouseY,mouseX/stage.stageWidth * 8,getTimer(),false,true);
    canvas.unlock();//when you're done changing pixels, commit the changes
}
```

So, back to the trails example:

```
var w:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var h:Number = stage.stageHeight;
var canvas:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w,h,false,0xFFFFFF);
addChild(new Bitmap(canvas));
var spheres:Sprite    = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;//add a container for all the spheres (planets/moons/sun/etc.)

var earthPivot:Sprite = spheres.addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;

var sun:Sprite     = spheres.addChild(getCircleSprite(69.5500 /4,0xFF9900)) as Sprite;
var earth:Sprite   = earthPivot.addChild(getCircleSprite(60.52 / 4,0x2233FE)) as Sprite;

earth.x   = 14960 / 40;
spheres.x = (w-spheres.width) * 0.5;
spheres.y = (h-spheres.height) * 0.5;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event):void{
    earthPivot.rotation   += 0.12;
    //draw trails
    drawTrail(earth,0x0000FF,canvas);
}

function drawTrail(s:Sprite,color:int,image:BitmapData) {
    var globalPos:Point = s.localToGlobal(new Point());//convert the local position of the sprite (it might have been nested several times) to the global/stage coordinate system
    image.setPixel(int(globalPos.x),int(globalPos.y),color);//colour a pixel at a set position
}

function getCircleSprite(radius:Number,color:int):Sprite{
    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(color);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(-radius * .5,-radius * .5,radius);//draw from centre
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    return circle;
}
```

Which looks like this:
[image: trails with pixels]

Not sure if it's what you want though, but pixels are fun to use and pretty fast too.
With a bit of math you can do some [minimal 3D](http://wonderfl.net/c/9ug3) as well.

Also, for your inspiration on drawing in actionscript, you can have a look at some of [Keith Peters'](http://www.artfromcode.com/), Erik Natzke, Joshua Davis, etc.

Comment: Up for the long explanation and great code! These kind of answers should be provided more often! :) Unfortunately as the guy said, it's too complicated for him and almost certainly he won't use it, but that's the proper way to do it. I admire you, because I didn't have patience nor I believed this kind of answer is needed, as I thought the guy asked the question won't use it - if he asks this kind of questions he won't understand that. Anyways - thumbs up! If someone really wants to learn, he should spent time reading things like that!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't such a command, but you can always create a very simple Sprite object and add it to the stage at the corresponding position. Something like:

```
var dot:Sprite = new Sprite();
dot.graphics.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
dot.graphics.drawRect(-1, -1, 2, 2);
dot.graphics.endFill();

dot.x = x;
dot.y = y;
addChild(dot);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If possible, can you please tell me what beginFill, drawRect and endFill do briefly, so that I can modify it for my needs?

Comment: It works out with the [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) Class of Flash - begins to fill something with specific color, then draws a rectangle, and finally ends filling it. Check out the spec.

Comment: I just tried it out - it doesn't seem to work. I copy pasted the code provided by you, but I don't get anything on the screen...what am I doing wrong? I have set the x and y in your 2nd last and 3rd last lines to the respective planet coordinates (which are working just fine).

Comment: @AndreyPopov that's one way to do it, but you'll be adding a new Sprite and drawing a new box every single frame/time you want to see a trail. I recommend creating a single transparent BitmapData instance, add it to a Bitmap on the bottom most layer/display list index and use the `draw()` method passing the planet's transformation matrix. Optionally you can even apply filters (such as a color transform to colour the trails or a faint blur to fade the trails over time if needed)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza, too complicated for me mate, still learning the basics! Can you break it down a bit?