# Actionscript: Very slow movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am drawing a circular line to varying degrees. I wish the animation to last about 0.5 seconds. For reasons I can not work out its running very slowly.

What is weird is that if I skip the tween and call the function tweenToNext it renders instantly.

```
        var degrees:int;
        var posX:int = 102;
        var posY:int = 102;
        var rad:int = 100;
        var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        addChild(mc);

        mc.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF0000, 1);
        mc.graphics.moveTo(posX, posY - rad)
        mc.i = -Math.PI / 2;

        tweenToNext();

        function tweenToNext(per:Number = 360):void {

            degrees += 1;

            if (mc.i <= (3 * Math.PI / 2) && degrees < per) {

                var x:Number = posX + Math.cos(mc.i) * rad;
                var y:Number = posY + Math.sin(mc.i) * rad;

                mc.graphics.lineTo(x, y); 
                mc.i += Math.PI / 180;

                TweenLite.to(mc, 0.001, {onComplete:tweenToNext});
            }

        }
```

I have tried Timer and setTimeout but these produce the same slow speed.

Comment: The more more complex the vector path, the slower rendering will get. I suggest either looking into [drawPath()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSA8BD9022-BAB1-46d3-9B26-0D9649743C8E.html) which should be more efficient or using a BitmapData instance to draw lines into.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227493/actionscript-3-0-tracing-the-path-of-a-moving-body/24229255#24229255)

Comment: Also please do not nest functions, you might mistakingly think they depend on the variables declared outside.

Comment: Organis is on the right track, but I have a suggestion. Instead of tweening for 0.0001ms (come on now ;)), tween according to your framerate. If your FPS is 30, one frame takes 33.3ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash application runs on frame-to-frame basis: *frame render - script execution - frame render - script execution - frame render - script execution* - and so on. That also means that whatever smallest delay you're putting there, the next call **will not** happen before next script execution phase, basically, next frame. Thus - guess what - your circle drawing takes 360 frames. 12 seconds if you have 30 FPS, for example.

If you want to make something synchronize with the real time, you need a different approach. I didn't check if this works, but I hope you'll get the idea and fix the mistakes if any.

```
var degrees:int;

var posX:int = 102;
var posY:int = 102;

var rad:int = 100;

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip;

addChild(mc);

mc.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF0000, 1);
mc.graphics.moveTo(posX, posY + rad);

// Now, magic time.
// Save time since app start (in milliseconds).
var startTime:int = getTimer();

// 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.
var drawingTime:int = 1000;

// Store the maximum degree to draw.
var degreeLimit:int = 360;

// Call it every frame.
mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onDraw);

function onDraw(e:Event):void
{
    // Now we need to check how much time passes since last frame
    // and update the drawing accordingly.
    var timeProgress:Number = (getTimer() - startTime) / drawingTime;
    var drawingProgress:Number = degrees / degreeLimit;

    // When the drawing progress catches the time progress
    // the loop will end. It will resume on the next frame.
    while (drawingProgress < timeProgress)
    {
        degrees += 1;

        // It's better than a property on target canvas,
        // which could be Sprite or Shape, they wouldn't take random fields.
        var anAngle:Number = degrees * Math.PI / 180;

        var tox:Number = posX + Math.cos(anAngle) * rad;
        var toy:Number = posY + Math.sin(anAngle) * rad;

        mc.graphics.lineTo(tox, toy);

        // We should know when to stop it.
        if (dergees >= degreeLimit)
        {
            mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME);
            return;
        }

        // Update the drawing progress.
        drawingProgress:Number = degrees / degreeLimit;
    }
}
```